# Simulate eager loading for non-associated tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got a `quality_code` field which is free-text entered by the user.  However, there are certain known codes with a longer description available.  If a known code is stored on the record, I would like to display the description in place of the code.

I've got a simple method on the model to show the description if available, or the entered quality_code if not, but it falls into the typical pattern of n+1 queries required to draw a list of n items:

```
def view_quality_code
  if (code = QualityCode.find_by_quality_code(quality_code)).nil?
    quality_code
  else
    code.description
  end
end
```

If the models were actually linked (`belongs_to :quality_code`) then I would sort this out by adding `includes(:quality_code)` to the query, so it would just do one extra query to the quality_code table.

Is there a simple way to do the same sort of thing without the models being linked?

Comment: Why aren't you linking the models?

Comment: Because I can't control the input into the quality_code field (I can't reject unknown values).  I would need to either create stub entries in the quality code table each time some random text was entered, or alternatively have two fields quality_code_text and quality_code_id

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably link the models and create new entries on the fly. That ensures that anything entered *becomes* a known code for future users -- is that what you want?

Comment: Alternatively, link the models and have a "none of the above" record that unknown codes get referred to (or just leave the association as nil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what your other model is called, I'll pretend it's "Widget." Assuming you have an array of widgets like so:

```
widgets = Widget.all
```

You can fake the eager loading yourself like this:

```
@codes = QualityCode.where(:quality_code => widgets.map(&:quality_code).uniq).group_by(&:quality_code) 

def view_quality_code
  if codes = @codes[quality_code]
    codes[0].description
  else
    quality_code
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks pretty good.  Because the QualityCode table is very small, I am just building the hash with Hash[QualityCode.all.collect{|c|[c.quality_code, c.description]}] and it seems to work much better.